# Using ElasticSearch Local version in postman

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I am trying to Use my Elastic search server installed in my local machine to use Postman .i.e., With the help of Postman I want to `Post` Data and retrieve it with a `get` operation but unable to do it as I am getting error `unknown key [High] for create index`

So please help me with the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a document to your index,
your url should look something like this ( for document ID 1 ) :

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/test/_doc/1
```

A good place to start :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index.html

Answer (score 2):

**For indexing document in the index**

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/_doc/1
```

[image]

**Retrieving indexed document**

```
GET http://localhost:9200/my_index/_doc/1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction:

**Elasticsearch** is a distributed, RESTful search and analytics engine capable of addressing a growing number of use cases. As the heart of the Elastic Stack, it centrally stores your data for lightning fast search, fine‑tuned relevancy, and powerful analytics that scale with ease.

**Kibana** is a free and open user interface that lets you visualize your Elasticsearch data and navigate the Elastic Stack. Do anything from tracking query load to understanding the way requests flow through your apps.

**Logstash** is a free and open server-side data processing pipeline that ingests data from a multitude of sources, transforms it, and then sends it to your favorite “stash.” .

Elasticsearch exposes itself through rest API so in this case you don't have to use logstash as we are directly adding data to elastic search

### How to add it directly

you can create an index and type using :

```
 {{url}}/index/type
```

where index is like a table and type is like just a unique data type that we will be storing to the index. Eg {{url}/movielist/movie

https://praveendavidmathew.medium.com/visualization-using-kibana-and-elastic-search-d04b388a3032